# Display form only if cookie is set in PHP and SQL?

Tags: php, sql, cookies, set

I'm writing a script in PHP. Once the user has logged into the website, I have set a cookie to run:

```
$cookie_name = "logged";
$cookie_value = $row['uid'];
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

They are then redirected back to the homepage. However, instead of being met with a login box in the top right corner of the webpage, I want the form to hide and information about the user to display instead. However, at the moment the login box stays, even once the cookie is set. Heres the code for the login box:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
echo '<form action="attempt.php" method="post">
<div align="right"><br />
Email Address:<br />
<input type="text" name="mail"><br />
Password:<br />
<input type="password" name="pword"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</div>
</form>
<div align="right"><br />
</div>';
} else {
print '<a href=" . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] . ".php">View my profile.</a>';
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice :)

Comment: are you initializing `$cookie_name` variable on home page, once you redirect user to it after setting cookie? Also you can use session instead of cookies to maintain user log in session.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vivek, how do I initialize the variable? I thought once I had done this on the previous page the cookie would be there in the background?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didnt initialized $cookie_name in login form.

Try this:

```
$cookie_name = "logged";//add this before checking
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
echo '<form action="attempt.php" method="post">
<div align="right"><br />
Email Address:<br />
<input type="text" name="mail"><br />
Password:<br />
<input type="password" name="pword"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</div>
</form>
<div align="right"><br />
</div>';
} else {
print '<a href="' . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] . '".php">View my profile.</a>';
}
```

If this doesnt resolve you problem, try to set error_reporting(E_ALL) and show to us any notice or warning.

Comment: No luck with that my friend :/ sorry i'm still in the noob stages of php, how do I do this error reporting?

Comment: try to add this function in the start of the php file: error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini_set("display_errors",1);